# Error detecting default configuration classes for test class

Tags: java, spring, testing, controller

so I am pretty new to Spring and testing. I want to test a `ResourceController` class in my project, and when i execute the test class standalone, it works and all the tests pass, but when i try to build the project or test it via Maven (mvn test) i encouter this error message, and all my test cases get skipped

```
2023-05-03T08:10:06.508+01:00  INFO 57176 --- [           main] t.c.s.AnnotationConfigContextLoaderUtils : Could not detect default configuration classes for test class [com.schrodingdong.resourcemanager.controller.Tests]: Tests does not declare any static, non-private, non-final, nested classes annotated with @Configuration.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes.lastModifiedTime()" because "this.attrs" is null
```

Here is my controller class :

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/resource")
@CrossOrigin
public class ResourceController {
    private final ResourceService resourceService;

    public ResourceController(ResourceService resourceService) {
        this.resourceService = resourceService;
    }

    @PostMapping("/upload")
    public ResponseEntity<?> uploadObject(@RequestParam ("file") MultipartFile multipartFile,
                                          @RequestParam String userMail,
                                          @RequestParam String resourceDescription,
                                          @RequestParam String resourceVisibility) throws ServerException, InsufficientDataException, ErrorResponseException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidResponseException, XmlParserException, InternalException {
        // ...
    }

    @GetMapping("/download")
    public ResponseEntity<?> downloadObject(@RequestParam String resourceId,
                                            @RequestParam String userMail,
                                            @RequestParam String downloadName) throws ServerException, InsufficientDataException, ErrorResponseException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidResponseException, XmlParserException, InternalException {
        //...
    }

    @NotNull
    private String getExtension(String fileName) {
        // ...
    }


    @DeleteMapping("/delete")
    public ResponseEntity<?> deleteObject(@RequestParam String resourceId,
                             @RequestParam String userMail) throws ServerException, InsufficientDataException, ErrorResponseException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidResponseException, XmlParserException, InternalException {
        // ...
    }

}
```

and here is the test class

```java
@WebMvcTest(ResourceController.class)
public class ResourceControllerTests {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    @MockBean
    private ResourceService mockResourceService;
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    }

    @Test
    void uploadObject() throws Exception {
                // ...
    }

    @Test
    void downloadObject() throws Exception {
                // ...
    }

    @Test
    void deleteObject() throws Exception {
                // ...
    }
}
```

As i mentioned im still new to spring and im still confused on what to do here, some insight would be highly appreciated !

*NOTE : I already have another controller class which get tested just fine standalone or with the mvn test command, so i really don't know where is the problem here*

Comment: Well it is telling you that the attribute of the File is null.

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes.lastModifiedTime()" because "this.attrs" is null`

Somewhere in your code you are doing` lastModifiedTime()` and trying to use it

Comment: I didn't use this method in my code at all, but one dependency is using it, after i dug deep in the debugger, and i can't just not use it